# Rails TDD: tests in another directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory, tdd

for a bigger rails application I implemented the ability to load plugins. Of course I want to test those plugins, too.

For a cleaner directory structure I created test/plugins/ and in this file several test case files.

Is there a possibility to run those tests similar to test/unit and test/functional with rake test and rake test:plugins?

Greetings,
 CK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own Rake task to test whatever you choose! In a `.rake` file under `lib/tasks`:

```
require 'rake/testtask'

namespace :test do
  Rake::TestTask.new :my_custom_tests do |t|
    t.libs << 'test' # if you need to `require 'test_helper'`
    t.pattern = 'test/custom_subdir/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end
```

Then you can run these tests using `rake test:my_custom_tests`.

If you want these tests to also run when you run your existing test task (i.e. `rake test`), you can enhance that task. In a Rails app the task that actually does the heavy lifting is `test:run` (`test` itself does a few other things first, including setting up your test db)

```
Rake::Task['test:run'].enhance do
  Rake::Task['test:my_custom_tests'].invoke
end
```